# Birth and death process - example transition probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, birth-death-process

> Suppose we have a birth-death process with state space S = $\{1,2\}$, $\lambda_1 = 2$ and $\mu_2 = 1$. Find transition probabilities.

---

I have drawn how my process looks like:

```
     --- 2 -->
  (1)         (2)
     <-- 1 ---
```

I also know that r.v. being waiting time between state 1 and 2 denoted $T_1$ is $$\text{Exp}(\lambda_1 + \mu_1) = \text{Exp}(2)$$. I am to calculate how $$\mathbb{P}_{i,n}(t) = \mathbb{P}(X(t)=n|X(0) = i)$$ looks like.

No further progress has been made. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinitesimal generator for this continuous-time Markov chain is
$$
Q = \begin{pmatrix}
-2 &2\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We can compute the transition probability matrix $P(t)$ by matrix exponentiation:
\begin{align}
P(t) &= e^{tQ}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(tQ)^n}{n!}\\
&= \large\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{3}+ \frac{2 e^{-3 t}}{3} & \frac{2}{3}-\frac{2 e^{-3 t}}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{3}-\frac{e^{-3 t}}{3} & \frac{2}{3}+\frac{e^{-3 t}}{3}.
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}